# Shell Script To Find Windows Partitions and Replace Desktop Image

Tags: linux, partition, windows, ntfs

I am in need of a shell script that will detect Windows partitions and replace the desktop image and place an image on the Desktop.

I need it to detect if there are multiple disks in on the computer, so it will do this to all disks in the computer, so if the user has two hard drives with two Windows OS and two usernames, it will do all of them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows...

Comment: It's not fully about Windows, it's about a shell script in Linux to detect Windows drives on a dual boot pc and place an image on the desktop of multiple users & multiple drives/partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Run from an up-to-date Linux distribution in a POSIX shell the following should list the contents of every Windows 7+ User folder on any disk in the system.

I don't know exactly where the desktop background is kept though - and I don't have a Windows installation - but hopefully the following is enough to go on.

```
mkdir /tmp/mnt 
(   set $(lsblk -pno FSTYPE,KNAME | grep -E '^([^ ]*fat)|(ntfs)')
    while sudo mount "${2:?}" /tmp/mnt
    do  ls /tmp/mnt/Users/*/
        sudo umount /tmp/mnt 
    shift 2; done            
) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I've just checked on my machine, the wallpapers are kept in C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg (x64)

is there anyway for Linux to detect the username on a windows drive?

Comment: @glynnrbower - sure if its a directory name. So could do like - in place of `ls` above - `cat image > /tmp/mnt/Users/$someuser/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Themes/background` or whatever the filename is to specifically target the user `$someuser`.

Comment: Thank you :) for your reply I will try to get it to work I haven't been on Linux for long.

Comment: How would I go about just placing an image file on the Desktop of the user in the same way?

Comment: Just like that - with the `cat` thing, right? I dunno - it depends on the filename of their current background. As I've said - I dunno what that filename is. If it is a common filename and the only difference is which user folder it is in, then you just do the `cat` thing with the `>` target being whatever that file name is.